# Efficient way to call multiple reduce functions on an iterable in Python?

Tags: python, performance, functional-programming, iterator, reduce

I'd like to run several reduce functions on an iterable in Python (2.7).  An example would be calling `min` and `max` on an iterable of integers.  But of course you can't call `reduce(min, it)` and `reduce(max, it)` on the same iterable, since it's exhausted after the first call.  So you might think to do something like:

```
reduce(lambda a, b: (min(a[0], b[0]), max(a[1], b[1])), ((x, x) for x in it))
```

And you think, Hey, that's pretty nifty, so you generalize it into something like this:

```
from itertools import izip

def multireduce(iterable, *funcs):
    """:Return: The tuple resulting from calling ``reduce(func, iterable)`` for each `func` in `funcs`."""
    return reduce(lambda a, b: tuple(func(aa, bb) for func, aa, bb in izip(funcs, a, b)), ((item,) * len(funcs) for item in iterable))
```

(And you like unit tests, so you include something like this:)

```
import unittest
class TestMultireduce(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_multireduce(self):
        vecs = (
            ((1,), (min,), (1,)),
            (xrange(10), (min, max), (0, 9)),
            (xrange(101), (min, max, lambda x, y: x + y,), (0, 100, (100 * 101) // 2))
        )
        for iterable, funcs, expected in vecs:
            self.assertSequenceEqual(tuple(multireduce(iterable, *funcs)), expected)
```

But then you try it, and you realize it's *really* slow:

```
%timeit reduce(min, xrange(1000000)) ; reduce(max, xrange(1000000))
10 loops, best of 3: 140 ms per loop
%timeit reduce(lambda a, b: (min(a[0], b[0]), max(a[1], b[1])), ((x, x) for x in xrange(1000000)))
1 loop, best of 3: 682 ms per loop
%timeit multireduce(xrange(1000000), min, max)
1 loop, best of 3: 1.99 s per loop
```

Ouch.  So then you come to Stack Overflow looking for Python optimization wisdom...

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's this, which kind of defeats the point of iterables...

```
def multireduce(iterable, *funcs):
    """:Return: The tuple resulting from calling ``reduce(func, iterable)`` for each `func` in `funcs`."""
    return tuple(imap(reduce, funcs, tee(iterable, len(funcs))))
```

But it is quite fast for my test case:

```
%timeit multireduce(xrange(1000000), min, max)
10 loops, best of 3: 166 ms per loop
```